# Powershell DoCmd.RunSQL query fails to update MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, powershell

I'm trying to update an MS Access table by running a query from Powershell.  I've simplified my code as follows:

```
Write-Host "Start Access ..."
$Acc = New-Object –com Access.Application

Write-Host "Open database ..."
$Acc.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\redacted\imh-test.accdb")

Write-Host "connected ..."
$Acc.DoCmd.RunSQL("update DeepcleanEntryDoor set Title = 'Mrs'")

Write-Host "Data appended, close Access ..."
$Acc.Quit()

Write-Host "... process complete!"
```

I get a "The RunSQL action was canceled." as follows:

```
Start Access ...
Open database ...
connected ...
Exception calling "RunSQL" with "1" argument(s): "The RunSQL action was canceled."
At line:8 char:1
+ $Acc.DoCmd.RunSQL("update DeepcleanEntryDoor set Title = 'Mrs'")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Data appended, close Access ...
... process complete!
```

I've also tried DoCmd.OpenQuery using an existing query, but get the same result.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

DB

Comment: Why not use the Access database as an ODBC data source and execute the query directly via ADO.NET?

Comment: @alroc I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say "He didn't know he could". DiamondBeezer, take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/04/use-ace-drivers-and-powershell-to-talk-to-access-and-excel.aspx) to get started with alroc's suggestion of connecting directly to the database and not having to run Access as a proxy. Once you get used to it you'll probably be happier for it in the long run.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I kinda knew about an alternative connection method, but stupidly assumed Access.application would be the way to go as it seemed less generic than ODBC...  Been struggling with this for a couple of days, so will check out your ADO idea and report back.  Cheers

Comment: @alroc,@TheMadTechnician - you were quite right. Downloaded and installed the ACE drivers and my update query works!
Not quite as straightforward as that of course - had to wrestle with 32-bit and 64-bit issues, versions of Powerpoint, versions of Access, 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine' etc, etc.  Got it all running from Powershell_ISE, but it then wouldn't run from Powershell itself (I need to do that for automation).  Despite actually running 64-bit Access 2013, it seems running the 32-bit Access 2010 components was the only way to get it working!